# Error: Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$mapGeoCoding

Tags: upgrade, error, core

I have just upgraded from CiviCRM 4.6 to 5.4.1. We are getting an error on our events pages

> Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$mapGeoCoding

I have tried to search for a fix, but have been unsuccessful. I tried removing `$config->mapGeoCoding` from the core EventInfo.tpl as another post suggests, but I couldn't find this line in this file under core.

Comment: Gareth You might want to check if you have installed any extension that still uses the old version of this file. Thanks
Yashodha